# Pandas merge does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn

[image]

I have the following 2 dataframes, and I wish to join them on the Date column.

When I try to do:

```
final_df = pd.merge(event_by_codes, stock_norm)
```

I get No common columns to perform merge on.
(The date is timestamp object)

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: you're not specifying on which columns to join or how to join

Comment: Either use `join`  or specify `left_index`  and `right_index` in merge. Also, please don't post images (that's the reason I am not able to provide you a working example as an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Date` is not a column... Its an index
- [**`merge`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) merges on columns... you want [**`join`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) which operates on indices
- make sure your indices are actually `datetime` and not strings

---

```
stock_norm.index = pd.to_datetime(stock_norm.index)
event_by_codes.index = pd.to_datetime(event_by_codes.index)

stock_norm.join(event_by_codes)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried join first but I got NaN on all values. The issue was that stock_norm df index was a string and not a timestamp (I noticed when you wrote).

Comment: @kjanko you'll noticed that I address that issue in my bullet points as well as fix the issue by reassigning the indices themselves.  Did you just try the `join` without reassigning the indices?